# Error with NSComparator: incompatible block pointer types initializing

Tags: objective-c, sorting, compiler-errors, objective-c-blocks, comparator

Doing this NSComparator:

```
NSComparator comparatore = ^NSComparisonResult(NSMutableDictionary *aDictionary, NSMutableDictionary *anotherDictionary) {
            return [[aDictionary objectForKey:@"Item"] localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:[anotherDictionary objectForKey:@"Item"]];
    };
lista = [listaNonOrdinata sortedArrayUsingComparator:comparatore];
```

I get this error:
**incompatible block pointer types initializing 'int (^)(struct NSMutableDictionary *, struct NSMutableDictionary *)', expected 'NSComparator'**

I've read about this error on this site and on the official guide, but I have not found the solution.

I've tried everything, maybe someone here can help me, or maybe someone knows how to do the same sort in another way.
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`NSComparator` is a block expecting two `id`s. You need to put `id` as the argument type, and do casting inside your block if necessary (in this case, it is not necessary):

```
NSComparator comparatore = ^NSComparisonResult(id aDictionary, id anotherDictionary) {
    return [[aDictionary objectForKey:@"Item"] localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:[anotherDictionary objectForKey:@"Item"]];
};
lista = [listaNonOrdinata sortedArrayUsingComparator:comparatore];
```